# Is it possible to load resource from server side directly to Browser's localStorage?

Tags: php

Is there any possibilities that i can push json string from php to directly browser's localStorage ?
What i can do now is :

```
localStorage.setItem('someData', '<?= $someJsonData; ?>');
```

But I don't want to see the data from $someJsonData in my browser page source.
Or i can send an ajax request after the browser finished loading for $someJsonData it's simple but that's not what i'm thinking now.

I know, It doesn't seem to be possible. I'm just curious if it is, as there are so may things I don't know.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yeah, i'm just curious :) thanks @AniketSahrawat